# How can I detect a merged cell above a select line using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, merge

From the image below, I want to write a vba where cells in the column b will be equal to group above. So for example, column b for Activity 1.1 and Activity 1.2 would be equal to Group 1, and column b for Activity 2.1 and Activity 2.2 would be equal to Group 2.

```
c d     e                   f                          g           h       i
```

[image]

Any ideas on where to start?  Currently I have a two macros:  One creates a group below a selected group and the other creates a line below a selected line.  I'm thinking that when creating a new line I could somehow equate column b to the closest merged cell above my new line.

How could I find the closest merged cell above a selected row?

The code to create a new line is below:

```
Sub newLine()

Dim currCell As Integer
Dim newCell As Integer
currCell = ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Cells(Selection.Row, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC4=""Complete"",1,IF(RC4=""Late"",2,IF(RC4=""At Risk"",3,IF(RC4=""On Schedule"",4,5))))"

With Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=1"
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
.FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)

.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=2"
.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
.FormatConditions(2).Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)

.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=3"
.FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
.FormatConditions(3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)

.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=4"
.FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
.FormatConditions(4).Font.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=5"
.FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
.FormatConditions(5).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With

Cells(Selection.Row, 4).Select
   With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Complete, Late, At Risk, On Schedule"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "Select Status"
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With


Cells(Selection.Row, 4) = "[Enter Status]"
Cells(Selection.Row, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

Cells(Selection.Row, 5) = "[Enter Activity]"
Cells(Selection.Row, 5).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Cells(Selection.Row, 6) = "[Enter Task]"
Cells(Selection.Row, 6).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Cells(Selection.Row, 7) = "[Enter Responsability]"
Cells(Selection.Row, 7).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Cells(Selection.Row, 8) = "[Enter Start Date]"
Cells(Selection.Row, 8).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Cells(Selection.Row, 9) = "[Enter Comp Date]"
Cells(Selection.Row, 9).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 9)).Font.Bold = False
Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 9)).Font.Size = 8
Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 9)).RowHeight = 11.25
Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 7)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 7)).NumberFormat = "General"

Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 8), Cells(Selection.Row, 9)).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 8), Cells(Selection.Row, 9)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was interested, here's how I solved this:

```
Sub testGroupNum()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
startRow = Selection.Row

For i = startRow To 11 Step -1
If Cells(i, 4).MergeCells = True Then
Cells(startRow, 2) = Cells(i, 4)
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

`MergeCells` can help you out here.

```
Sub WhichLineIsMerged()

    Dim row As Long

    For row = ActiveCell.row To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(row, 1).MergeCells Then

            MsgBox "There are merged cells in row " & row

        End If

    Next row

End Sub
```

This sub only checks one cell on each line. As written, it checks Column A. You can adjust as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Actually, the only thing I ended up needing was the Step -1.